# CMake remove escape character from generator expresion

Tags: cmake

I have the generator expression `GEN_EXPR_INCLUDE_PATHS`  that provides a list of the directories to include.
The goal is to pass this list directly as compiler option via `add_custom_command`:

```
    add_custom_command(
                OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_FILE_NAME}.gch
                DEPENDS ${HEADER_FILE} IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX ${HEADER_FILE} 
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} 
                        ${FLAGS} 
                        ${HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS} 
                        ${gccGarbageCollectorOpts} 
                        -c ${HEADER_FILE} -o 
                        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_FILE_NAME}.gch
    )
```

Where HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS is following generator expression:

```
$<1:-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Some_Target,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>, -I>>
```

Just because the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of `Some_Target` is received as generator expression.

But cmake adds escape chars before spaces, and gcc fails due to these extra chars.

Is it possible to do something with it?
I'll be appriciate for any support.

Comment: "The goal is to pass this list directly as compiler option via add_custom_command" - `add_custom_command` accepts parameters for COMMAND as a list (semicolon-separated elements), no needs to separate elements with spaces. Could you show example of your `add_custom_command` invocation? Also, the tailing space `${GEN_EXPR_INCLUDE_PATHS }` seems a typo: it implies to dereference a variable with a **space in the name**: "`GEN_EXPR_INCLUDE_PATHS `".

Comment: @Tsyvarev, here it's: add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_FILE_NAME}.gch
            DEPENDS ${HEADER_FILE}
            IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX ${HEADER_FILE}
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
                    ${FLAGS}
                    ${HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS}
                    ${gccGarbageCollectorOpts}
                    -c ${HEADER_FILE}
                    -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_FILE_NAME}.gch
        )

Comment: And HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS is $<1:-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Some_Target,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>, -I>>

Comment: My problem is that property INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of Some_target contains generator expression, so I should somehow to deal with it.

Comment: This is valuable information, but, as you can see, comments are badly suited for the code. Please [edit] your question post and add this code into it. Also fix typos in your code (like a tailing space after the variable's name). Take into account, that on Stack Overflow comments are "second-class" citizens, and all important information should be in the question post itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

`add_custom_command` accepts COMMAND parameters as a **list**. In CMake a list is a string which elements are separated by **semicolon**, so it is semicolon which should be used for joining, not a *space*.

Also, for correctly split semicolon-containing strings, `add_custom_command` needs `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` keyword.

```
set(HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS -I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:mylib,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>,;-I>)

add_custom_command(
            ...
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} 
                    ...
                    "${HEADER_INCLUDE_PATHS}" # Double quotes are important!
                    ...
            COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS # This option is important too
)
```

---

Actually, an example with a space-separated join of include directories

```
-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>, -I>
```

is provided in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#string-valued-generator-expressions) itself. Not sure about their intention for this example.

Comment: Thanks for useful info. 
Onenote: I had to use $<SEMICOLON> instead of ';' in generator expression.