# custom target with target_link_libraries in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, module

I have a custom target for emit module interface. How can I link custom target with libraries?

```
function(add_module TARGET)
    set_source_files_properties(${ARGN} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

    add_custom_target(${TARGET}.pcm
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
            -std=c++20
            -fmodules
            -fimplicit-modules
            -fbuiltin-module-map
            -fimplicit-module-maps
            -c "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${ARGN}"
            -Xclang -emit-module-interface
            -o "${PREBUILT_MODULE_PATH}/${TARGET}.pcm"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    )
    add_library(${TARGET} ${ARGN})
    add_dependencies(${TARGET} ${TARGET}.pcm)
endfunction()
```

```
add_module(raytrace src/raytrace.cpp)
target_link_libraries(raytrace stl) // not working
target_link_libraries(raytrace.pcm stl) // (1)
```

(1) produces

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:75 (target_link_libraries):
  Utility target "raytrace.pcm" must not be used as the target of a
  target_link_libraries call.
```

stl is interface library added via add_subdirectory(stl)

Comment: What do you mean by `// not working` comment for the line? It should link the library `raytrace` with the `stl`.

Comment: `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${ARGN}"`: Why not declare an additional parameter. If there are more than 2 parameters passed to the function this would probably result in issues.

Comment: @Tsyvarev raytrace.pcm can't find any headers from stl interface library

Comment: "raytrace.pcm can't find any headers from stl interface library" - This seems to be logical, as your **custom** target, which creates `raytrace.pcm`, doesn't specify include directories. CMake commands like `target_include_libraries` or `target_include_directories` affects only on command lines, **generated by CMake** itself. CMake never modifies COMMAND for custom target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My question exactly about this. How to specify target_include_libraries for custom target, or how to create module properly, without custom target?

Comment: "how to create module properly, without custom target?" - According to your code, you have already check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300495/how-to-use-c20-modules-with-cmake, and its answers states that currently you cannot do that. "How to specify target_include_libraries for custom target" - In your custom COMMAND you could try to use `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:raytrace,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>` generator expression, which extracts include directories from your library target. Like in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450808.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, It's working! But now I have one more problem  /home/maxim/CLionProjects/minecraft/src/main.cpp:29:1: fatal error: module '_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t' is defined in both '/home/maxim/.cache/clang/ModuleCache/2Y5MCJ5ENFIL7/_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t-1HITC614MVKMY.pcm' and '/home/maxim/.cache/clang/ModuleCache/XFMJMT840WAT/_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t-1HITC614MVKMY.pcm'

Comment: I would suggest to inspect **actual command line** with the compiler invocation, which is generated by CMake, and find out which its parameter(s) is wrong.